# Filter inside ForEach activity in Azure Datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I was trying to filter an array based on values from different array. As filter activity doesn't allow arrays inside conditions, so, I am trying to filter one array by iterating over each value in second array. However, while writing the condition in the "Filter Activity", I am unable to reference "item()" value of the ForEach loop (value from second array on which iteration is running). Is there a way to reference outer item() inside filter activity?
I saw a post which showed we can use -: `items("ForEachActivity")` to refer foreach activity's values however, it throws an error -: `{"code":"BadRequest","message":"ErrorCode=InvalidTemplate, ErrorMessage=The template validation failed: 'The workflow action 'FilterFilter1' at line '1 and column '42236' references the action 'ForEach1' of type 'Http': only the actions of type 'foreach' are allowed to be referenced by 'repeatItems' or 'items' functions","target":"pipeline/TableIeratorPipeline/runid/f332271e-4628-4a3f-95a2-7794e3a4216f","details":null,"error":null}` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a variable to save the current item from For Each activity.

My test:

1.create three variables in pipeline.
[image]

2.create a For Each activity and check `Sequential` option.
[image]

3.pass value of current item to variable.
[image]

4.determine whether two values are equal.
[image]